# How to fix a toilet that flushes too hard?

Tags: toilet, water-pressure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make our toilet flush less vigorously?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/488/how-do-i-make-our-toilet-flush-less-vigorously)

When I flush my toilet, the pressure is such that it actually splashes up quite a bit.  (It's kinda gross.)

How do I fix this?